# alternate option for window object in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

When we try to encrypt and decrypt the application for front end request and response data,

Window object is not getting support in Jmeter.

As it generate 2 session id .

Kindly let us know any method in Groovy to support .

Answer (score 0):

- [Window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) is specific to the **browser**
- As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

  > **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however **JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript** found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So there is no equivalent in any language supported by [JMeter's JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

The options are in:

- Use [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) for getting the session IDs you're looking for, they can be passed later on to "normal" HTTP Request samplers (but this way each JMeter virtual user will kick off a real browser instance)
- Extract the code responsible for request encryption and session ID generation using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and convert it to something JMeter could execute (remove the browser context), preferably in Groovy as it's the most performing scripting option